# Google Maps API, problem creating mutliple markers with infowindows via loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The problem I am having with the below code is that the info window only pops up on the last iterated marker, even when i click on the first marker the infowindow on the last marker is opened?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        map.setMapType(G_NORMAL_MAP);
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(-29, 24), 5);

        var cIcon = new GIcon();
        cIcon.image = '/img/gmap_marker-01.png';
        cIcon.shadow = /img/gmap_marker_shadow-01.png';
        cIcon.shadowSize = new GSize(80, 25);
        cIcon.iconSize = new GSize(48, 32);
        cIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(23,31);
        cIcon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(5, 1);
    }

var coords = {
96 : {lat: -29.11813, lon: 26.223091},
97 : {lat: -34.041023, lon: 18.444715},
98 : {lat: -29.857003, lon: 31.024794},
99 : {lat: -33.93264, lon: 25.56995},
100 : {lat: -26.201452, lon: 28.045488},
101 : {lat: -25.746019, lon: 28.18712},
142 : {lat: -33.960396, lon: 22.456244},
143 : {lat: -32.991009, lon: 27.901569},
144 : {lat: -31.89701, lon: 26.873444},
145 : {lat: -28.744031, lon: 31.889691},
146 : {lat: -27.75588, lon: 29.933845},
147 : {lat: -28.737811, lon: 24.766211},
148 : {lat: -26.870491, lon: 26.664465},
149 : {lat: -25.668498, lon: 27.242372},
150 : {lat: -25.864549, lon: 25.642374},
151 : {lat: -25.4701, lon: 30.97808},
152 : {lat: -23.912257, lon: 29.45355}
};

    markerOpts = {icon : cIcon};

    for(branchId in coords){
        var point = new GLatLng(coords[branchId]['lat'], coords[branchId]['lon']);

        var marker = new GMarker(point, markerOpts);

        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            marker.openInfoWindowHtml('hello');
        });
        map.addOverlay(marker);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because loop hasn't a scope so marker will be the latest one created in your loop. You have to wrap your loop content in a function:

```
for (branchId in coords) {
    function() {
        var point = new GLatLng(coords[branchId]['lat'], coords[branchId]['lon']);

        var marker = new GMarker(point, markerOpts);

        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            marker.openInfoWindowHtml('hello');
        });
        map.addOverlay(marker);
    }(branchId)
}
```

Comment: The inline function didn't work in my case (got error: function statement requires a name). So I had to define a new function with a name and the arguments it requires (i.e. map, coords, markerOpts, branchId). Then I had to call the function by name from within the loop and pass the required arguments.